# IO exception even after including try catch block

Tags: android

The following piece of code is creating error

```
Activity context;
context = new Activity();
try {
    InputStream configAsset = context.getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("MyConfig.cfg");
    //SimpleSpkDetSystem alizeSystem = new SimpleSpkDetSystem(configAsset, context.getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getPath());

}catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "File not found for recording ", e);
}
```

Error:

```
Error:(255, 87) error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Even after I included the try,catch blocks why is it creating an error?

Comment: Try catching the 'IOException' instead of FileNotFoundException, let me know if it works

Comment: you are catching `FileNotFoundException`, not `IOException`.

Answer (score 2):

Change your code like this :

BEFORE:

```
Activity context;
        context = new Activity();
        try {
            InputStream configAsset = context.getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("MyConfig.cfg");
            //SimpleSpkDetSystem alizeSystem = new SimpleSpkDetSystem(configAsset, context.getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getPath());

        }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "File not found for recording ", e);
        }
```

AFTER:

```
Activity context;
        context = new Activity();
        try {
            InputStream configAsset = context.getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("MyConfig.cfg");
            //SimpleSpkDetSystem alizeSystem = new SimpleSpkDetSystem(configAsset, context.getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getPath());

        }catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "File not found for recording ", e);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, `IOException` is the parent of `FileNotFoundException`. So catching the `IOException` will ensure you catch any exception that is a subclass of `IOException`.

```
Activity context;
context = new Activity();
try {

    InputStream configAsset = context.getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("MyConfig.cfg");
    //SimpleSpkDetSystem alizeSystem = new SimpleSpkDetSystem(configAsset, context.getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getPath());

}catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "File not found for recording ", e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should include the following to avoid the crash,

```
        try {
            InputStream configAsset =getApplication().getAssets().open("MyConfig.cfg");               
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("ddsa", "File not found for recording ", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("ddsa", "IOException  ", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Also the context you set not work well for me that's why `getApplication()`